# Regex to match specific characters in a string and modify it

Tags: json, regex

I am very bad at creating Regular Expression. therefore, thought of asking for help here. I tried googling but was not able to get much out from there.

I have a Json object that I have converted to a string. The result is as below:

```
{
    "ContainerId": "<script>alert('hi')</script>>>",
    "AssociateId": "abc22<script>",
    "Header": {
        "ApiVersion": null,
        "JsonWebToken": null,
        "MessageId": "<script>1de11a8e-</script>b6df-4835-aba0-5d9ea59acf59"
    },
    "StoreNumber": "9913"
}
```

I actually wanted to encode the values of the Json object. So I thought of using regex to match below value from the json and when value found, replace all next value till the closed double inverted commas.

**Value to match :**

**: "**

**Example**

```
"ContainerId": "<script>alert('hi')</script>>>",
```

I only wanted to encode value here that occur right after **: "**

I was successful encoding the value via using Jproperty, but now wanted to do that via Regex.

Comment: You don't need regex for this. Use any JSON parser and encode values

Comment: yes, for that I have to loop for every jason value. and it the json object has multiple children than I have to loop through them as well. I have achieved it but I want to get rid of loop here

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/8eHmHz/1)?

Comment: Even with regex you will need a loop as you want to encode not just simple string replace.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the regex that matches your requirement**

> :[\s]\"(.*?)"

You will find your data in the first match group, You can try it [Here](https://regex101.com/)

Now to replace those occurrences, it would depend on the programming language you use.